# how to calculate the missing quantity and items in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion

I have a product which is made of many x materials, each material can be made of other materials or be pure. If they are made of other materials, it is specified which materials are need with their needed quantity and currently available quantity for the item. I want to calculate how many material I have and I don't have, and for the material I don't have, I want to sum all the missing quantities.

Right know I am getting right the material quantity in the "first level" when the product is missing a material which is not used in submaterials. When I try to sum the missing submaterials the operation is not right.

How can I calculate the materials needed to create a product and each materials?

Here is the code I write:

```
const product = {
    name: 'prod_1',
    quantity: 1.2,
    material_quantities: [
      { id: 2, quantity: 2 },
      { id: 1, quantity: 2 },
    ],
  };
  const materials = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'material1',
      quantity: 1.2,
      material_quantities: null,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'material2',
      quantity: 1.2,
      material_quantities: [{ id: 1, quantity: 2 }],
    },
  ];

  function areEnoughMaterials(materialId, neededQuantity) {
    const mainMaterial = materials.find(id === materialId);

    const inStock = parseFloat(neededQuantity) <= parseFloat(mainMaterial.quantity);

    if (mainMaterial?.material_list?.length === 0 && inStock) {
      materialsStatus.available[materialId] = mainMaterial.quantity;
    }

    if (!inStock) {
      if (!materialsStatus.missing[materialId]) {
        materialsStatus.missing[materialId] =
          parseFloat(neededQuantity) - parseFloat(mainMaterial.quantity);
      } else {
        materialsStatus.missing[materialId] =
          materialsStatus.missing[materialId] + parseFloat(mainMaterial.quantity);
      }
    }

    if (mainMaterial.material_quantities) {
      for (const material of mainMaterial.material_quantities) {
        

        areEnoughMaterials(material.id, material.quantity);
      }
    }
    return;
  }

  let materialsStatus = {
    available: {},
    missing: {},
  };

  for (const material of product.material_quantities) {
     areEnoughMaterials(material.id, material.quantity);
  }
```

The output I am expecting is this:

```
{
   available: { 2:1.2, 1:1.2 },
   missing:{  2:0.8,  1:3.6  }
}
```

Comment: what is the expected value of this example?

Comment: @ITgoldman I updated the answer. In order to calculate the missing quantity of the material with ID 1 i did this: `2:1= x:0.8`, I calculate x which is 1.6: we need 2 item material1 to make 1 material2 and the 0.2 of material2 in material1 is 1.6 Then I added  2 from the need material1 in product. I don't know if am doing right the math :/

Comment: ok i get it now. this seem fun. but pay attention you need 1.2 of `product` not 1.

Comment: @ITgoldman 1.2 in product object is the quantity of the product present. I need to do another one. To make 1 complete product I use 2 from material 1 and 2 from material 2

Comment: @ITgoldman now I've used another logic: I summed all present quantity of each material and summed all quantities of needed materials, then I subtract each needed quantity from available quantities. And I got this solution: {2:0.8, 1:2.8}  for missing materials.

Comment: I really think your data structure is confused.  Is there any real distinction between a product and a material?  Raw materials clearly have `material_quantities: null`, but wouldn't it make more sense to have `prod_1` in the same structure as the material?  Then we would need a function that takes a material name and quantity and the material list and return... what?  Wouldn't you want the results, after you've used up your composite materials of only the raw materials remaining?  Or is there a way to break these composites back into their component parts for reuse?

Comment: Here is [a structure](http://link.fourwindssoft.com/75) I could imagine.